# RegEx for currency missing single digit numbers?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I have the following RegEx ...

```
(\d*,?){1,5}\.?\d{2}
```

... and it will successfully match everything **execpt** the single digit `9`'s in this listing ...

```
9
99
999
9,999
99,999
999,999
9,999,999
99,999,999
999,999,999

9.99
99.99
999.99
9,999.99
99,999.99
999,999.99
9,999,999.99
99,999,999.99
999,999,999.99

9
99
999
9999
99999
999999
9999999
99999999
999999999

9.99
99.99
999.99
9999.99
99999.99
999999.99
9999999.99
99999999.99
999999999.99
```

... can you help me match those as well? Maybe the entire RegEx is wrong and I'm just getting lucky?

### Usage

I'm using this in a client-side `RegularExpressionValidator`.

### Technology

ASP.NET Web Form 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you're seeking some digits and/or commas, followed by an optional point, followed by exactly two (non-optional) digits. You're also allowing e.g. `99,.99`.

Try

```
\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?
```

which is at least one digit, followed by zero-or-more groups of (comma digit digit digit), followed by an optional group of (point digit digit).

Comment: Just to note, it will allow `12323435464,567,456` (i.e. the first group can be any length) - you'd need the first bit to be `\d+|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)` to make it restrict to perfect-commas-or-no-commas.